# not adding css for changing id - reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm creating a popup in React js and have a div with a changing id based on a boolean `gameOver.winner`
Right now I have set `gameOver.winner` to true.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { AppContext } from '../../../App'
import './GameOver.css'

const GameOver = () => {
    const { currAttempt, setCurrAttempt, grid, setGrid, gameOver, setGameOver} = useContext(AppContext)
    console.log(gameOver.winner)
    return (
        <div className="gameOver" ** id={gameOver.winner}> **
            <div className="gameOverInner">
                <h1>Game Over</h1>
                <h2>{gameOver.winner ? "You Win!" : "You Lose!"} - {currAttempt.currRow}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
export default GameOver
```

In `GameOver.css` I am calling this id

```
.gameOver[id=true]{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

However, my output has no styling to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `gameOver.winner` is a boolean, then it's not going to output a `<div id="true">` node to the DOM. React doesn't accept boolean values for the id prop on intrinsic html elements (you should see an error in the browser console regarding it). If you want to add special styling to your div based on a boolean value, I'd suggest adding a class to it when `gameOver.winner` is true.

```
<div className={`gameOver ${gameOver.winner ? 'winner' : ''}`}>
```

Then in your css file you can target it with the selector `.gameOver.winner`.